# Oracle: Export & Dump file only creates tables, no data

Tags: oracle10g

I have in Oracle Exports a schema with 100 tables database size 30 GB.  The dump file Size is  2 mb.

When I import the dump file (2 mb) into a new database, all the tables are empty but the user tablespace is 30 GB  although all tables are empty?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that the 30GB database was exported into a 2 mb file with data. It must have been exported with rows=n parameter.  Hence when you import it, the tables are empty

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to export without data.

```
expdp username/password DIRECTORY=directory_object_name DUMPFILE=dumpfile_name 
TABLES=table_names|TABLESPACES=tablespace_names|FULL=y CONTENT=metadata_only
```